# Can cats distinguish whether the meow sounds come from real cats or speakers?

Tags: cats

Often hear some people play meow soundtrack with phones or speakers for cats, and the cats seems feel surprised, but the problem is, do they surprise for unknown cats? Or just because of unfamiliar machine soundtrack?

Comment: I can't think of any possible way to test either hypothesis short of serious lab testing with brain activity scanning.

Comment: I've played with my pets this way, my cats sometimes react to it, but my schnauzer always does, she looks and sniffs the speaker, wondering why she can't see the kitten, but this is not a study at all, just some random games we play with our pets

Comment: From experience, I will say that cats generally know the difference between a speaker or an actual source when they have experience with the source (IE my cat ignores my voice from the phone), but even if they know it sounds differently, that may not mean that they differentiate between other sounds that they might not be familiar with (like an unfamiliar cat's meow, or explosions on the TV).

Comment: IMO, any source of sound that piques their interest has fooled them. But are they just *playing the game* ? We'll probably never know in our lifetime. However I doubt it; they're always on the lookout for some new-sounding-thing to eat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experience, I will say that cats generally know the difference between a speaker or an actual source when they have experience with the source (IE my cat ignores my voice from the phone), but even if they know it sounds differently, that may not mean that they differentiate between other sounds that they might not be familiar with (like an unfamiliar cat's meow, or explosions on the TV).